# Macro delimiter

Tags: macros, tex-core, delimiters

I'd like to have a macro to split up another macro content, with field separator being a space. So:

```
\def\mytext{foo bar}
\def\secondof#1 #2{#2}
\secondof\mytext
```

What? What do you mean: "runaway argument"? Oh right, I guess `\mytext` counts as only one argument and you're expecting two. Ok, so

```
\expandafter\secondof\mytext
```

and indeed, the result is "bar", just as I was hoping for.

But alas, then comes something rather surprising:

```
\def\firstof#1 #2{#1}
\expandafter\firstof\mytext
```

"fooar"? You got to be kidding me! How on earth did you—dear and beloved TeX—ever come to such a ridiculous decision? You did so well with the `\secondof`, after all. What gives?

*(just to make this a complete MWE, I'm going to add a `\bye` here)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\firstof foo bar` will simply take `foo` as first argument and `b` as second one. So the `ar` is left afterwards and will by typeset as ordinary text. For that reason you got `foo` + `ar` = `fooar` as result.

If you don't want this behaviour, you need to add an end delimiter, `\nil` or `\@nil` is often used for that purpose:

```
\def\firstof#1 #2\nil{#1}
\expandafter\firstof\mytext\nil
```

Now #1 will get `foo` and #2 will get all the rest until `\nil`, i.e. `bar`.

Comment: Ah, an end delimiter, ofcourse! Thanks! But how come the `\secondof` works as expected?

Comment: @morbusg: Change the definition of secondof to `\def\secondof#1 #2([[#2]])` and you'll see what is happening.

Comment: And more importantly, how did the `#2` "bleed" into the `#1`?

Comment: `\secondof` did not worked as expected. `\expandafter\secondof\mytext` gives you only `b`. The `ar` is left and will be typeset as ordinary text, so the end result will be `b`+`ar`. (The same way `\firstof` gave you `foo` + `ar` = `fooar`.) Change `\secondof` to `\def\secondof#1 #2{(#2)}` and you'll see that only the `b` will be typeset in parens.