# xstring macros inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, xstring

I don't really understand what is the problem here, but I guess it has to do with expansion and fragile macros since when I do the same outside of `\path` it works.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\aw}{10pt}
\newcommand{\bbw}{20pt}
\newcommand{\cw}{30pt}

\newcommand{\width}[1]{%
  \StrBefore{#1}{'}[\notprimed]
  \IfEndWith{#1}{'}
  { \csname \notprimed w\endcsname }
  { \csname #1w\endcsname }
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \name in {a,bb,c,a'}
{ ++(\width{\name},0pt) node {\name} };

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % \draw (0pt,0pt) node {s}
  %   ++(\aw,0pt) node {a}
  %   ++(\bbw,0pt) node {bb}
  %   ++(\cw,0pt) node {c}
  %   ++(\aw,0pt) node {a'};

  \draw (0pt,0pt) node {s}
    \foreach \name in {a,bb,c,a'}
    { ++(\width{\name},0pt) node {\name} };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I think it has to do with `xstring` also because when I remove the `\StrBefore` and `\IfEndWith` from the definition of `\width` it also works.

Any ideas?

Comment: So why don't you just take the first letter no matter what comes in the `foreach` loop instead of testing for prime?

Comment: @percusse Because the name of the macros don't have only one letter in my code and don't have the same length either. In any case, I don't think that would change anything right? (I edited the question to reflect the fact that in my code the macros don't have only one letter and don't have the same length)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The problem seems to be in `(\width{…},0pt)` as `\width{…}` is not just a length but includes all the `xstring` stuff, too. You will need to do that outside of the path (or inside of `\pgfextra`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How can I do it outside of the path? I've been also thinking about that but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the usage of the `xstring` macros outside of the coordinates as they are not fully expandable and do not result simply in `\csname #1w\endcsname`.

With `\pgfextra{<stuff>}` or `\pgfextra <stuff> \endpgfextra` you can do `<stuff>` that does not belong into a path.

It seems to me, you just want to strip a trailing `'` from, so you could simply do:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\width}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{'}{}[\qrr@width]%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\widthresult\csname\qrr@width w\endcsname}
\makeatother
```

and use it in

```
  \foreach \name in {a,bb,c,a'}{
    \pgfextra{\width{\name}}
    ++ (\widthresult,0pt) node {\name}
  }
```

---

The following solution strips everything after the first `'` and works (due its simplicity) even inside a coordinate.

#### Reference

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16595)
- [Macro delimiter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36325/16595) (one of many)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\aw}{10pt}
\newcommand{\bbw}{20pt}
\newcommand{\cw}{30pt}
\makeatletter
\def\strip@upquote#1'#2\@strip@upquote{#1}
\newcommand{\width}[1]{\csname\expandafter\strip@upquote#1'\@strip@upquote w\endcsname}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0pt,0pt) node {s}
  \foreach \name in {a,bb,c,a'}{
    ++ (\width{\name},0pt) node {\name}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are those `\expandafter` for?

Comment: @Ricardo It builds the `\csname …\endcsname` sequence before `\let`ting it to `#2`. Otherwise you would try to do `\let#2\csname` and a trailing `<some stuff>\endcsname` which will fail. That said, I fear you could optimize your `\width` code but I do not know your rules for the names and what should taken from it to build `\…w`. Do you just want to strip any occurrence of `'`?

Comment: Yes, that all I need. I know there's only one `'` and it's always at the end.

Comment: @Ricardo I have updated my answer explaining a little bit and added a very basic solution for your use-case.